# Is it possible to override standard Save button?

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Earlier a question was posed where the user asked if a warning message could be popped instead of an error message while saving a record.

So my approach was to create a button which replicates the `Save` button functionality but has an `alert` popping up with the error.

I could not find any examples where a record was created from scratch capturing all the values inputted using a Javascript button. Is it possible?

Comment: Why does the error need to appear as a pop-up? I would recommend sticking to standard error message handling so you don't have to handle unique error reporting needs in various interfaces (classic, lightning, API).

Comment: If you still feel it necessary, are you primarily interested in this behavior for a classic or lightning UI? The design patterns would be different.

Comment: Well I came across a scenario where somebody wanted to display a warning message which still allowed the user to save the record. This cannot be achieved using standard error message handling. And this would be on classic UI

Comment: In classic, you could build a VF page to override the edit page. Then override the default `save` method to apply a message to the screen the first time the user clicks. An alternative could be to create a VF page embedded on the standard record view page that displays messages you want the user to be aware of.